# How to detect `XMLHttpRequest` response HTTP Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We are using third party JS codes on our site. We would like to track the every ajax call. This is working fine on tracking but **how can we detect the response? Especially the HTTP code**.

```
(function () { // scope saves you from infinite loops / loss of __xhr
    var __xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest; // back up
    function XMLHttpRequest() { // wrap
        console.log(
            XMLHttpRequest.caller || arguments.caller || 'caller not supported'
        );
        return new __xhr;
    }
    window.XMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest; // shadow
}());
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could register to listen to load event like this [one](https://medium.com/@gilfink/quick-tip-creating-an-xmlhttprequest-interceptor-1da23cf90b76)